# How to calculate size of metal plate for a specified current?

Tags: batteries, current, resistivity

So I'm looking at running a plate from the terminal of a battery (26650) and I'm trying to calculate the width of the plate needed given a certain thickness and length as well as a specified current. I have the resistivities of various metals (in order to calculate the best option (price and size of plate) but I'm not sure how to proceed/ what equation I could use. If someone could link me to a webpage with information that would be amazing!
Itachi

Comment: What on earth does "running a plate" mean? I'm guessing some sort of heating device, but you'll have to be a lot more specific about what your requirements are.

Comment: How much cooling air flow will you provide?

Comment: @DaveTweed I meant something like this https://imgur.com/k9o2hl4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you mean something like a busbar or solid metal conductor with a rectangular cross-section.

1. You know \$ \rho \$ and its units are Ω⋅m (ohm-metre).
2. If you divide that by the cross-sectional area of your conductor you will have \$ \frac {Ω \cdot m}{m^2} = \mathrm {Ω/m} \$ which is the resistance per metre of your conductor.
3. If you multiply the figure obtained in 2 by the length of the conductor you will get \$ \frac {\Omega}{m} \cdot m = \Omega\$, the resistance of the conductor.
4. From \$ V = IR \$, using R calculated in 3, you can calculate the voltage drop along the conductor for a given current, \$ I \$.
5. From \$ P = I^2R \$ you can calculate the power in watts (W) dissipated in the conductor.

Amazing?